# Bootstrap responsive image height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need the images be in the same height and at the same time responsive, but I don't understand how to do this.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <img style="width : 100%" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/1743484_1417876895127107_960615052_n.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <img style="width : 100%" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/1016354_762185537132820_936517474_n.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G26mN/

Comment: You are missing one closing `</div>` tag. Or is it just typo?

Comment: error in writing the question (FIXED)

Comment: In my mind you'll have to give fixed height or use bigger images.

Comment: Can you put you code on jsfiddle for testing ? Thank

Comment: if i give a fixed height it will looks very bad in other devices

Comment: So use bigger images and give the following styling to them `<img style="max-height : 100%; max-width: 100%;"`

Comment: its not an option for me because later image will be dynamic about the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G26mN/

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
img {
width: inherit;  /* Make images fill their parent's space. Solves IE8. */
max-width: 100%; /* Add !important if needed. */
height: auto;    /* Add !important if needed. */
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but i need the images be in the same height and in the same time responsive

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/1743484_1417876895127107_960615052_n.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/1016354_762185537132820_936517474_n.jpg" alt=""  />
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help but left and right images are not in the same height :(