# CSS: Responsive images in a row cut to same height according to the smallest image

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I have 2 images in a row, which are of different height. The structure is build using Bootstrap grid.

I want the images to be responsive according to the width of viewport, but at the same time they has to be of **equal height at every moment**. (otherwise the texts below are scattered)

HTML:

```
   <div class="item container active">
         <h1>Lorem IPSUM</h1>

        <div class="row items-holder">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img />
                <p class="title">SOME TITLE</p>
                <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img/>
                <p class="title">SOME TITLE</p>
                <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.items-holder img {    
    width: 100%;    
    height: auto;    
    max-height: 450px;    
    overflow: hidden;    
    display: block;    
}
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64CLd/

Similar problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324072/bootstrap-responsive-image-height), but the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: There is really no way to dynamically adjust the height of each row according to the smallest height of each image without using javascript. However, if there is a minimum height on each image you can limit them to that.

Comment: What you are asking is logically not possible, if they are responsive to the width of the screen, the images will obviously loose their ratio and be distorted if you make them of equal height. Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible but CSS sucks :) here you have an example fully functional using javascript another option you do not have but to use javscript: http://jsfiddle.net/3y35w/6/

If max-height: 450px is removed images will continue with responsive dimensions:

```
var fitImages = function(){
    $("#img1").removeAttr( "style" );
    $("#img2").removeAttr( "style" );
    var changedWidth = $("#img1").height();    
    var h1 = $("#img1").height();
    var h2 = $("#img2").height();
    //it can be done only with height but using double check          ratio of the images is a bit more acurate
    if (changedWidth < OrigWidth) //expand
    {
        //using higher image as refference when maximize
        if (h1 > h2)
        {
          $("#img2").height(h1);  
        }
        else if (h2 > h1)
        {
            $("#img1").height(h2);  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //using lower image as refference when minimize 
       if (h1 < h2)
        {
          $("#img1").height(h2);  
        }
        else if (h2 < h1)
        {
            $("#img2").height(h1);  
        }
    }
    OrigWidth = changedWidth;
    return 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a new row for the title and subtitle

http://jsfiddle.net/64CLd/2/

```
<div class="col-xs-6 gueas">           
            <div><p class="title">SOME TITLE</p>
                <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p></div>
            <div><p class="title">SOME TITLE</p>
                <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This solves the problem with scattered titles, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is wrap the img tag in a `div` and give some `height` to the div. This will help you keep a consistent height, independent of the image height.

Following this, to vertically center align the image use the below css

CSS

```
.items-holder img {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    top:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
    margin: auto;

    }

.img_holder{ 
   height: 450px; //This can also be calculated dynamically with javascript as the max height within all images. 
   position:relative; 
   background:#ddd; //Optional 
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="img_holder">
    <img src="https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t1.0-9/10380889_10204383083927507_6950941830183040199_n.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/64CLd/3/)